# UILabel color and font size changes from the XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, uilabel, xib

I'm having some issues with an app i'm working on.

It used to work just fine, but now I noticed that many of the UILabel I have in my XIB have a font and color reset.

For example, if I set a white or red color in my XIB, it appears black when I run my app.

If I set the color programmatically, it will work fine.. But that would mean that I have to reset the color for all the labels I have in my XIB files...

As I said, it used to work just fine... I compared a XIB file with an older revision using SVN, it's the same file, but the labels are still appearing with a changed color...

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this ?

Note : I use Xcode 5.1.1 and the bug only occurs when I test on a device with iOS 5.

Comment: Can you isolate where the error might be coming from in your code and show that?

Comment: I will try comparing SVN revisions until I find the difference, but it may take some time. If i ever find the reason why I'll post it here. Until then, if anyone has some clues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was wrong... It seems like another developer wrote this code in the app :

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:14]];
```

And it behaves poorly on iOS5... But it solved my problem.

Now I have to find a proper way to change the color and font of a placeholder in a UISearchBar.

Answer (score 1):

please check whether you set the appearance somewhere or not.

```
[UILabel appearance] setBackgroundColoer:
```

It is better to setup your UI component appearance attribute programmatically

Comment: as i said, i know it would work, but since it used to work just fine and not anymore, i would like to know if there could be another way to fix it. it's a project with a 50+ xib, i don't want to spend a few hours just by doing it programmatically.